# Argument labels '(format:, _:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: swift

I am trying to run the following code and I get an error. 
Any ideas? 
Thanks!

```
var acctNumber = 27306
var accountType = "Savings"
var balance = 7503.35

print (acctNumber)
print (accountType)
print ("Your balance is" + String (format:"%.3f",balance))
```

Comment: Please try to explain your environment how to reproduce the issue. Are trying your code on a Xcode Playground? Or working on a Command Line Tool project? You see that just on the source code editor of Xcode? Or some build time log is showing that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though `String` is part of the standard Swift library, it appears that the `format` initializers are not.

Adding `import Foundation` fixes the issue:

```
import Foundation

var acctNumber = 27306
var accountType = "Savings"
var balance = 7503.35

print (acctNumber)
print (accountType)
print ("Your balance is" + String (format:"%.3f",balance))
```

Comment: Unrelated: replace `+` with `,` to automatically add a space